# Save a screenshot as pdf or high resolution-image using Swift 5 xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, printing, resolution, pdfkit

Found here: How do I take a full screen Screenshot in Swift?

```
func getScreenshot() -> UIImage {
    var window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0] as? UIWindow
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window!.frame.size, window!.isOpaque, 0.0)
    window!.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

My image includes much stuff of text on a page in DIN A4-format. The quality of the image is very poor for printing it. Is there any chance to increase the resolution?

The best way would be to save the screenshot as pdf. Is there any help here to save and refind the image.pdf in my device.

Thx for any hint.

Comment: To increase the resolution you would need to create a new UIView much larger than your app window, add all your content there and render that view.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find the way to present the pdf or to use the UIDocumentInteractionController yet and hope for the PDFKit is wright for useful presentation without increasing my UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your image to pdf via PDFKit

```
import PDFKit
let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: screenshotImage) 
let fm = FileManager.default urls = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! 
let savedPDF = urls!.appendingPathComponent("pdfPage.pdf") pdfPage?.document?.write(toFile: "pdfPage")
```

Comment: Thx. I don't find my pdf in the directory of my iPad and cannot present it by f.e. UIDocumentInteractionController or sharing by activityViewController or with Mailcomposer as attachment.  Where can I find more help.                                                                        pdfPage = PDFPage(image: screenshotImage)
 let fm = FileManager.default
 urls = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! 
 let savedPDF = urls!.appendingPathComponent("pdfPage.pdf") 

pdfPage?.document?.write(toFile: "pdfPage")

Comment: i see i will edit if i find something new for you. happy coding